# How can i use floating button in my react web site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, button, material-design

I want to hide and show a sidebar using a floating button in my React Website, and i have no idea how to do it.

I tried to use `react-floating-action-button` but then i realize that is a `React Native` component, not a web one and it doesn't works to me.

Exists another component library or a way to do it using reactstrap or something like that?

Comment: Hi Brian, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tried to use react-floating-action-button but then i realize that is a React Native component, not a web one and it doesn't works to me.*

I think this statement is not correct, you can use `react-floating-action-button` with web also.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wwhqat)

**Note:** You need to properly set the `font-awesome`, to get the icons.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much. I didn't know about this usage of the library.

Comment: Link is broken. Demo doesn't work. Although the answer is correct, you can use react-floating-action-button with web

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ant design for React? Have a look at its [Drawer](https://ant.design/components/drawer/) component.

Once you implement it. It will be easy to make the button float wherever you want on the page with plain css.

Comment: I gonna test it the next time, it would be better for my projects. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use tailwindcss:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<style>
  body {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>

<button title="Contact Sale" class="fixed z-90 bottom-10 right-8 bg-blue-600 w-20 h-20 rounded-full drop-shadow-lg flex justify-center items-center text-white text-4xl hover:bg-blue-700 hover:drop-shadow-2xl hover:animate-bounce duration-300" > &#9993; </button>
```